# Pattern matching Tkinter child widgets (winfo_children) to determine type

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, pattern-matching

I'm trying to automatically clear all `Entry` widgets in a parent widget.

```
import Tkinter
import re
root=Tkinter.Tk()

E1=Tkinter.Entry(root)
E1.pack()

E2=Tkinter.Entry(root)
E2.pack()

L1=Tkinter.Label(root,text='Label1')
L1.pack()
```

I'm running into 3 problems

1. While I can find out the children widget type, I can't seem to be able to use it in a pattern match. Printing out the `wlist[0]` below is different from the shell output?

Eg:

```
>> wlist=root.winfo_children()
>> wlist
[<Tkinter.Entry instance at 0x00000000151911C8>,
 <Tkinter.Entry instance at 0x00000000151BAD88>,
 <Tkinter.Label instance at 0x00000000151B29C8>]

>> wlist[0]    # shell output
<Tkinter.Entry instance at 0x00000000151911C8>

>> print wlist[0]   # print output here is different vs shell output above
.353964488L
```

2. I think due to the differences between the print output & shell output above, my pattern match can't work?

Eg

```
>> re.search(r'Entry',wlist[0])
    << No output >>
```

3. Assuming one is able to determine via pattern match that a child widget is indeed an `Entry` widget, how would you get the widget object itself to perform a `delete` method call?

Eg:

```
## Assuming I have a function to to clear the entry
## How would I pass the object from the pattern match in #2 to this function?
def clear_entry(objEntry):
    objEntry.delete(0,Tkinter.END)
```

Comment: use `type(wlist[0]) == Tkinter.Entry` or `isinstance(wlist[0], Tkinter.Entry)`. And `wlist[0].delete(0,Tkinter.END)`.

Answer (score 17):

The items returned from `winfo_children()` is a list of widgets. Tkinter widgets have a method to tell you the underlying widget class: `winfo_class`.

```
>>> wlist[0].winfo_class()
'Entry'
```

You can also simply compare the object type, like you can with any other python object:

```
>>> isinstance(wlist[0], Tkinter.Entry)
True
```

Since the result of `winfo_children` is a list of widgets, you can iterate over them and clear out all of the entry widgets like this:

```
for widget in root.winfo_children():
    if isinstance(widget, Tkinter.Entry):
        widget.delete(0, "end")
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you store them in a list or some container.

```
entry_list=[E1, E2]

def clear_entry():
    for id in entry_list:
        id.delete(0,Tkinter.END)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check typu using

```
if type(wlist[0]) == Tkinter.Entry:  # True/False
```

or better

```
if isinstance(wlist[0], Tkinter.Entry): # True/False
```

`wlist[0]` is object so you can do

```
wlist[0].delete(0,Tkinter.END)
```

and

```
clear_entry(wlist[0])
```

When you try to print object it use `str()` to convert object to string

```
print str(wlist[0])

.353964488L
```

shell use `repr()` to convert object to string

```
print repr(wlist[0])

<Tkinter.Entry instance at 0x00000000151911C8>
```