# Getting all of the Entry text content from a frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-entry

If I had a Frame named as the variable `table` which has multiple Entry widgets within this Frame, would there be a way of getting all the Entry widgets' text content?

Comment: where is the minimal code to debug

Comment: [iterate over all child widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995783/python-tkinter-how-to-delete-all-children-elements), and [get their text content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815063/get-contents-of-a-tkinter-entry-widget)

Comment: Actually, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667710/pattern-matching-tkinter-child-widgets-winfo-children-to-determine-type-pytho) is a better dupe for iterating over the child widgets

Comment: Thanks @Aran-Fey

Comment: You could also create all entry widgets in a list and iterate over that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the example below when the button is clicked every child in a parent widget is checked whether are equal or not to be an entry, then their contents are printed:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def get_all_entry_widgets_text_content(parent_widget):
    children_widgets = parent_widget.winfo_children()
    for child_widget in children_widgets:
        if child_widget.winfo_class() == 'Entry':
            print(child_widget.get())


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    table = tk.Frame(root)
    for _ in range(3):
        tk.Entry(table).pack()
    tk.Button(table, text="Get",
        command=lambda w=table: get_all_entry_widgets_text_content(w)).pack()
    table.pack()
    tk.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

One could have a much better `get_all_entry_widgets_text_content` method based on how the entries are instantiated, however, this one should work for all direct children regardless.